# Entering Schengen country via connection from another Schengen country

Tags: schengen, transit, international-travel

I have a Schengen visa type C issued by the French embassy, and my wife has a Schengen visa type C issued by the Greek embassy. Due to some changes of plan, we now both want to travel to Paris. We want to book a flight on Aegean Airlines from our non-EU home country; this flight will have a connection at Athens, Greece.

Do they stamp our Visas at the Athens Airport as our Schengen point of entry? 
Will I have a problem because my visa is from France? Will my wife be able to enter Paris without a problem because her visa is issued by the Greek embassy?

Comment: Is this the first time you are traveling on these visas?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes it is our first Shengen visas.

Comment: I assume your wife has a multiple entry visa?!

Comment: In principle, you can image the Schengen area being a large country. So your passports are stamped *entering* the area but typically not while travelling *inside*. There are no differences (concerning immigration/passports) between travelling domestically and travelling intra-Schengen internationally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the rules, you should not have any issues; as long as your visas are not restricted in any way and are valid for the entire Schengen zone.

Make sure you have copies of documentation you provided at the embassy for your visas as you may be asked to produce these at the immigration counter.

Once your passports are stamped at Athens, the remainder of your journey will not have any immigration formalities as you would be traveling within the Schengen zone; however due to the heightened security (especially in France), you may be asked to show your passports at Paris.

Comment: So both of our passports shall be stamped at Athens even if it is only our connection airport?

Comment: Yes, as this is your point of entry into the Schengen zone.